# ASP.Net Core unit tests "do not match framework/platform settings"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core application that includes the main project, two library projects, and a unit test project. When I run the unit tests, it complains:

```
[7/14/2019 9:55:38 PM Informational] ------ Discover test started ------  
[7/14/2019 9:55:39 PM Warning] Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.  
Indigo.UnitTests.dll is built for Framework 2.2 and Platform AnyCPU.  
Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings.

[7/14/2019 9:55:41 PM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 140 found (0:00:02.2274457) ==========  
[7/14/2019 9:55:41 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------  
[7/14/2019 9:55:41 PM Warning] Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.  
Indigo.UnitTests.dll is built for Framework 2.2 and Platform AnyCPU.  
Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings.
```

The unit tests apparently run correctly. I've stared at my project configurations, and I've read the referenced article, but I can't figure out what it's complaining about. I've Googled the error message, but the stuff I've found doesn't seem to apply to my situation.

Here are my csproj files (FWIW):

The main project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>xxx</UserSecretsId>
    <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>xxx</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
    <ApplicationInsightsAnnotationResourceId>xxx</ApplicationInsightsAnnotationResourceId>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <DotnetPublishFiles Include="App_Data/**/*">
            <DestinationRelativePath>App_Data/%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
        </DotnetPublishFiles>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\ajax.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\captive-page.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\captive-page.min.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\datepicker.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\datepicker.min.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\ihi-validation-extensions.min.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\jquery-validation.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\main.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\signalr.js" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\bundles\signalr.min.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\ajax.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\captive-page.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\captive-page.min.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\datepicker.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\datepicker.min.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\ihi-validation-extensions.min.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\jquery-validation.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\main.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\main.min.css" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\signalr.js" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\bundles\signalr.min.js" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Flee" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Humanizer" Version="2.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="3.5.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Neleus.DependencyInjection.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sakura.AspNetCore.Mvc.PagedList" Version="2.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sakura.AspNetCore.PagedList" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sakura.AspNetCore.PagedList.Async" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="5.31.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\ihi.Lib.Web\ihi.Lib.Web.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\ihi.Lib\ihi.Lib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Identity\Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\ajax.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\captive-page.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\captive-page.min.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\datepicker.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\datepicker.min.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\ihi-validation-extensions.min.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\jquery-validation.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\main.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\signalr.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\bundles\signalr.min.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The unit test project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\ihi.Lib.Web\ihi.Lib.Web.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\ihi.Lib\ihi.Lib.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Indigo\Indigo.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The first library project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="libphonenumber-csharp" Version="8.10.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" Version="2.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The second library project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Braintree" Version="4.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Markdig" Version="0.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.6.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.11.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ihi.Lib\ihi.Lib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: It complains about the reference used in your unit test project `<ProjectReference Include="..\Indigo\Indigo.csproj" />`. It is not in the correct format/framework.

Comment: Ok, I give up... what is incorrect about that project reference? (For extra points, explain how Visual Studio 2017 managed to create the invalid project reference [I'm now using VS 2019]. And for even more points, explain why it's never complained to me until very recently. And for even MORE points, explain why people are down-voting this question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be fixed in Visual Studio 16.2.2.

Comment: Getting the exact same issue in VS 16.4.2.  First test project I added in my solution is fine.  The second test project I added I'm getting "Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.  IntegrationTests.dll is built for Framework.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1 and Platform AnyCPU".  Tried removing the project and adding it back, creating new project, cleaning solution, restarting VS, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated from Visual Studio 16.1.x to 16.3.3, and I was having similar issues.  I normally run my tests using a ".runsettings" file, and I found I had to do two things:

- Remove the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` setting from the ".runsettings" file.
- In the Build menu, run "Clean Solution". (Without this, test runner results would not show up in Test Explorer.)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this one on VS 2019 16.5.2 - turns out the project was updated to Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 16.5 - downgrading to 16.2 fixed my issue. I got v16.2 by successivley downgrading one version at a time. 16.4 and so on.

Seems Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 16.5 requires NET Core 3.0+